# How to configure Grafana dashboard uid for Ray dashboard?

Tags: python, ray

The default uid is `rayDefaultDashboard` (e.g. https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/ray-2.4.0/dashboard/client/src/pages/metrics/Metrics.tsx#L201-L202), is that configurable?

E.g. I'll have two dashboards for two ray clusters, how can I tell them apart in the Dashboard UI.